# How to show pages on right side with panel in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am able to implement panel .But i need  my pages should display with panel.Actually when i click panel button's then it hide panel .show page on whole screen .But i need to show page with panel.

Here is my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/TXRjk/2/

Jump to second page
            Jump to third page

#### First Page

Next
        

        
            Open Pannel

```
<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#index" data-role="button">Jump to first page</a>
        <a href="#third" data-role="button">Jump to third page</a>        
    </div>    

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Second Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="third">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#index" data-role="button">Jump to first page</a>
        <a href="#second" data-role="button">Jump to second page</a>        
    </div>    

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Third Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question i need to show pages in front of panel.Run my fiddle .it show  open panel .when i click button which is present on panel it show pages but i need to show pages in front of panel in right side with panel

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be what you're wanting:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">  
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="btnPages" data-idpage="index">Jump to index page</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="btnPages" data-idpage="second">Jump to second page</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="btnPages" data-idpage="third">Jump to third page</a>        
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3 id="header-page">
            First Page
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content-page">
        <a data-role="button" href="#mypanel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer-page">
        .
    </div>

</div> 

<div class="soHide" id="index">  
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3 id="header-index">
            First Page
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content-index">
        <a data-role="button" href="#mypanel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer-index">
        .
    </div>

</div> 

<div class="soHide" id="second">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3 id="header-second">
            Second Page
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content-second">
        <p>this is a second page</p>
        <a data-role="button" href="#mypanel">Open Pannel again</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer-second">
       footer second page
    </div>
</div>

<div class="soHide" id="third">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3 id="header-third">Third Page</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content-third">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel one more time</a>
        <p>it's third!</p>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer-third">
        it's some third footer page
    </div>
</div>
```

and this javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnPages', function(){   
    var page = $(this).attr('data-idpage');
    var header = $("#header-"+page).html();
    var content = $("#content-"+page).html();
    var footer = $("#footer-"+page).html();

    // apply
    $("#header-page").html(header).trigger('create');
    $("#content-page").html(content).trigger('create');
    $("#footer-page").html(footer).trigger('create');
});
```

and this css:

```
.ui-panel-animate {
    transition: transform 1350ms ease 0s !important;
}
.soHide { display: none; }
```

and this functional example http://jsfiddle.net/wgbn/Hxy37/